# A basic question expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables respectively such that $E[X]=1$ and $E[Y] =0$ , $X^2 + Y^2=1, |X|\leq 1,|Y|\leq 1 $. Is it true that $X=1$ a.e. This has been used in some proof in Athreya Lahiri Probability Theory book. I don't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{Var}X=\mathbb{E}X^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}X\right)^{2}=\mathbb{E}\left(1-Y^{2}\right)-1=-\mathbb{E}Y^{2}\le 0$ implying that $\text{Var}X=0$

Then $X=\mathbb{E}X=1$ a.s.